# Form of Reaction-Advection-Diffusion Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

My textbook (*Essential Partial Differential Equations* by Griffiths, Dold, and Silvester) says the following:

> $$u'' = a(x)u' + b(x)u - f(x)$$
>
> This is called a reaction-advection-diffusion equation since the second derivative term represents "diffusion", the term $a(x)u''$ represents "advection" (if $a > 0$ then there is a "wind" blowing from left to right with strength $a$) and the term $b(x)u$ represents "reaction". The term $f$ is often called the "source" term.

I'm guessing that should be $a(x)u'$ instead of $a(x)u''$?

I tried researching this, but every time I found an equation that was described in a similar way to the above one, it was in a [wildly different form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation#Equation).

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, the advection term is $a(x) u'$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Harry49 Done! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the book should speak of the *stationnary version* of such an equation.
Indeed, if we consider the following reaction-advection-diffusion equation
$$
\partial_t u + a(x) \partial_x u = \partial_{xx} u - b(x) u + f(x)
$$
and seek for its steady-state solutions ($\partial_t u=0$), we obtain the above differential equation.

Now, let us consider the convection-diffusion equation from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation):
$$
\partial_t c + \nabla\cdot (\vec v c) = \nabla\cdot(D\nabla c) + R \, .
$$
The use of the words convection and advection is the same in this context, so that the previous equation could be called an advection-diffusion equation. Under the assumption of incompressible flow ($\nabla\cdot \vec v = 0$), the convection term becomes
\begin{aligned}
\nabla\cdot (\vec v c) &= \vec v\cdot\nabla c + c\nabla\cdot \vec v\\
&= \vec v\cdot\nabla c \, .
\end{aligned}
For a constant diffusion coefficient $D=1$, the diffusion term becomes $\nabla\cdot(D\nabla c) = \nabla^2 c$. In the case of one-dimensional flow with velocity $\vec v = v \vec x$, we therefore have
$$
\partial_t c + v \partial_x c = \partial_{xx} c + R \, ,
$$
which corresponds to the previous reaction-advection-diffusion equation, where the reaction coefficient is $b(x) = 0$.

Comment: Wikipedia has written the stationary version as $0 = \nabla \cdot (D \nabla c) - \nabla \cdot (\mathbf{v} c) + R$. How does this relate to what you have written?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.